# Need double quotes in each column while spooling data from oracle database to Excel file

Tags: sql, oracle

I am automating a process wherein I run a SQL query through batch and the output is spooled into a csv file. 
Requirement: Each field of csv file should have double quotes.

Ex :

```
Currently the output is PROJ_SHORT_NAME,WBS_SHORT_NAME
                        CGL1,CGL1 
Required output is "PROJ_SHORT_NAME","WBS_SHORT_NAME"
                   "CGL1","CGL1"
```

SQL Query :

```
set verify off
set trimout off
set trimspool off
set feedback off
set linesize 22000
set pagesize 200
col csv_string FORMAT a1200
set colsep ','
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET ECHO OFF

SPOOL E:\PDE_GPO\outputfile1.csv

select * from <tablename>;

SPOOL OFF
exit;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The || concatenates items together. 
You can do:

```
SELECT '"'||col1||'","'||col2||'","'||...
FROM table
```

That would produce something like:
row 1: "col1val","col2val","col3val"...
row 2: ...

The down-side is you have to list/know every column you want to pull, but best coding practices would state you should specify the columns anyways (in case things are added/removed you want to be sure you get what you want).

-Jim

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. 
I had to import set markup csv on and the issue got resolved.